# Observables in Angular 2 and Observable<T>

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I am writing a method for Angular 2 handle http.get requests, and with a return type Observable.  As you can see the intent is for it to return an object which can take "any" shape from parsed JSON.
Questions: 1) Is Observable< any>  "code smell" 2)If "yes", recommended strategy to rework this?

```
executeQuery(url: string, requestOptionsArgs: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<any> { 
  return this.http.get(url, requestOptionsArgs).map(this.extractData).catch( error => {
     console.log('DataManagerService error thrown: ' + error );
     return Observable.throw(error )
  }) ;
}
```

Comment: What does `extractData` do? By the way `.map(this.extractData)` should probably be `.map(response => this.extractData(response))`.

Comment: Processing data... here it is:       
 private extractData(res: Response) {
           
   var result =  {"status": res["status"],"statusText": res["statusText"],"type": res["type"], "headers": res["headers"] ,
            "Body":  res.json()};

            return result || {};
        
  }

Comment: That returns something a lot more specific than `any`, so it seems odd that you would throw away its type. You should make an interface to hold that 'result' type.